# Access a dynamically created textbox text from another sub. And I also want to be user-configurable and access the user-configured text

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Textbox.text I want to access. And I want it user-configurable before I want to access the altered text.

```
Dim qbox As New TextBox
        qbox.Size = New Size(20, 20)
        qbox.Location = New Point(90, 10)
        qbox.Parent = addtocart
        qbox.Name = "quarts"
        qbox.Text = "ss"**
```

how I dynamically add it inside a series of other dynamic controls:

```
tile.Controls.Add(addtocart)
            flpp.Controls.Add(tile)
        tile.Controls.Add(plabel)
        tile.Controls.Add(nlabel)
        addtocart.Controls.Add(qbox)
```

How I tried to access it:

```
qb.Text = CType(Me.Controls("flpp").Controls("tile").Controls("addtocart").Controls("qbox"), TextBox).Text
```

I generated to textbox at runtime. Of course it's dynamic. I'm new to VB and I'm just experimenting a school project. I wanted the textbox text to be configurable and then access that configured value. I've been brain-cracking for days about this. when I run the thing, I "getObject reference not set to an instance of an object." under NullReferenceException was unhandled" something like this. I don't get it.

Comment: the control you created is named "quarts" not "qbox".

Comment: Nearly all NullReference Exceptions have the same set of causes.  See [NullReference Exception in Visual Basic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26761773/1070452) for help on this.  This wont be the last time you get an NRE

Answer (score 0):

WinForms?  If yes, and you want to find that control "by name", then use the [Controls.Find()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(v=vs.110).aspx) function:

```
Dim ctlName As String = "quarts"
Dim matches() As Control = Me.Controls.Find(ctlName, True)
If matches.Length > 0 AndAlso TypeOf matches(0) Is TextBox Then
    Dim tb As TextBox = DirectCast(matches(0), TextBox)
    ' ... use "tb" somehow ...
    Dim value As String = tb.Text
    MessageBox.Show(value)
End If
```